# Why does this LCS (Longest Common Subsequence) Python implementation with memoization performs badly?

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization, lcs

I am learning Dynamic Programming and came across the LCS (Longest Common Subsequence) algorithm.

I have implemented several versions of it in Python, to see how implementations differ from each other and how they perform.

Here is the code:

```
import time
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(50000)


def current_milli_time(): return time.time() * 1000


def memoize_decorator(fn):
    cache = {}

    def inner_fn(*args):
        if args in cache:
            return cache[args]
        ret = fn(*args)
        cache[args] = ret
        return ret

    inner_fn.__name__ = fn.__name__
    inner_fn.__doc__ = fn.__doc__
    return inner_fn


class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'


class TestORedAssertValue:
    def __init__(self, *ored_assert_values):
        self.__values = ored_assert_values

    def assert_value(self, value):
        for self_value in self.__values:
            if self_value == value:
                return True
        return False

    def values(self):
        return list(self.__values)


def test_assert(label, value, assertValue, *args):
    ok = False
    assertToPrint = assertValue
    if isinstance(assertValue, TestORedAssertValue):
        ok = assertValue.assert_value(value)
        assertToPrint = " OR ".join(map(str, list(assertValue.values())))
    elif value == assertValue:
        ok = True
    if ok:
        print('#', label, ' - ', bcolors.OKGREEN, 'ok', bcolors.ENDC, sep='')
    else:
        print('#', label, ' - args: ', ", ".join(map(str, args)), ', expected: ', assertToPrint,
              ', got: ', value, ' - ', bcolors.FAIL, 'fail', bcolors.ENDC, sep='')


def measure_time_decorator(fn):
    def inner(*args):
        start = current_milli_time()
        ret = fn(*args)
        end = current_milli_time()
        print('time: ', end - start, ' ms', sep='', end=' - ')
        return ret
    inner.__name__ = fn.__name__
    inner.__doc__ = fn.__doc__
    return inner


def test(fn):
    print()
    print("Testing:", fn.__name__)

    fn = measure_time_decorator(fn)

    A = ['A', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'G', 'C', 'E', 'D', 'B', 'G']
    B = ['B', 'E', 'G', 'C', 'F', 'E', 'U', 'B', 'K']
    assertRes = ['B', 'E', 'G', 'C', 'E', 'B']
    res = fn(A, B)
    test_assert('testcase 1', res, assertRes, A, B)

    A = ['A', 'B']
    B = []
    assertRes = []
    res = fn(A, B)
    test_assert('testcase 2', res, assertRes, A, B)

    A = []
    B = []
    assertRes = []
    res = fn(A, B)
    test_assert('testcase 3', res, assertRes, A, B)

    A = [1, 2]
    B = [1, 2]
    assertRes = [1, 2]
    res = fn(A, B)
    test_assert('testcase 4', res, assertRes, A, B)

    A = [1, 2]
    B = [1, 2]
    assertRes = [1, 2]
    res = fn(A, B)
    test_assert('testcase 5', res, assertRes, A, B)

    A = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'L']
    B = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'L']
    assertRes = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'L']
    res = fn(A, B)
    test_assert('testcase 6', res, assertRes, A, B)

    A = [x for x in range(3000)]
    B = A
    assertRes = A
    res = fn(A, B)
    test_assert('testcase 7', res, assertRes, A, B)

    A = [x for x in range(3000)]
    B = list(reversed(A))
    assertRes = TestORedAssertValue([0], [2999])
    res = fn(A, B)
    test_assert('testcase 8', res, assertRes, A, B)


def longest_common_subsequence(A, B):
    N = len(A)
    M = len(B)
    res_matrix = [[[]] * (M + 1) for i in range(N + 1)]
    for i in range(1, N + 1):
        for j in range(1, M + 1):
            if A[i - 1] == B[j - 1]:
                res_matrix[i][j] = res_matrix[i - 1][j - 1] + [A[i - 1]]
            else:
                res_matrix[i][j] = res_matrix[i][j - 1] if (
                    len(res_matrix[i][j - 1])
                    >
                    len(res_matrix[i - 1][j])
                ) else res_matrix[i - 1][j]
    return res_matrix[-1][-1]


def longest_common_subsequence_recursive_memoized(A, B):
    N = len(A)
    M = len(B)
    if N <= 0 or M <= 0:
        return []
    res_matrix = [[[]] * M for i in range(N)]

    @memoize_decorator
    def recursion(i, j):
        if i <= -1 or j <= -1:
            return []
        elif A[i] == B[j]:
            res_matrix[i][j] = recursion(i - 1, j - 1) + [A[i]]
        else:
            prev1 = recursion(i - 1, j)
            prev2 = recursion(i, j - 1)
            res_matrix[i][j] = prev1 if (
                len(prev1)
                >
                len(prev2)
            ) else prev2
        return res_matrix[i][j]

    recursion(N - 1, M - 1)
    return res_matrix[-1][-1]


def longest_common_subsequence_recursive_memoized_mit(A, B):
    N = len(A)
    M = len(B)
    if N <= 0 or M <= 0:
        return []
    res_matrix = [[None] * M for i in range(N)]

    def lcs(i, j):
        if i <= -1 or j <= -1:
            return []
        if res_matrix[i][j] == None:
            if A[i] == B[j]:
                res_matrix[i][j] = lcs(i - 1, j - 1) + [A[i]]
            else:
                prev1 = lcs(i - 1, j)
                prev2 = lcs(i, j - 1)
                res_matrix[i][j] = prev1 if (
                    len(prev1)
                    >
                    len(prev2)
                ) else prev2
        return res_matrix[i][j]

    return lcs(N - 1, M - 1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test(longest_common_subsequence_recursive_memoized)
    test(longest_common_subsequence_recursive_memoized_mit)
    test(longest_common_subsequence)
    print()
```

The important functions are:

- `longest_common_subsequence_recursive_memoized`: Uses recursion with memoization through a `memoize_decorator`;
- `longest_common_subsequence_recursive_memoized_mit`: Uses recursion with memoization achieved by directly checking `res_matrix` (inspired by this MIT lecture -> https://youtu.be/V5hZoJ6uK-s?t=3228);
- `longest_common_subsequence`: A dynamic programming implementation using a `n * m` matrix without recursion;

If you run the code above (e.g. `python longest_common_subsequence.py`), you will see an output similar to the following:

```
$ python longest_common_subsequence.py

Testing: longest_common_subsequence_recursive_memoized
time: 0.22802734375 ms - #testcase 1 - ok
time: 0.0048828125 ms - #testcase 2 - ok
time: 0.003173828125 ms - #testcase 3 - ok
time: 0.02099609375 ms - #testcase 4 - ok
time: 0.01806640625 ms - #testcase 5 - ok
time: 0.046875 ms - #testcase 6 - ok
time: 328.40087890625 ms - #testcase 7 - ok
time: 105788.96801757812 ms - #testcase 8 - ok

Testing: longest_common_subsequence_recursive_memoized_mit
time: 0.22607421875 ms - #testcase 1 - ok
time: 0.0048828125 ms - #testcase 2 - ok
time: 0.003173828125 ms - #testcase 3 - ok
time: 0.031005859375 ms - #testcase 4 - ok
time: 0.01416015625 ms - #testcase 5 - ok
time: 0.041015625 ms - #testcase 6 - ok
time: 255.93994140625 ms - #testcase 7 - ok
time: 26466.174072265625 ms - #testcase 8 - ok

Testing: longest_common_subsequence
time: 0.159912109375 ms - #testcase 1 - ok
time: 0.011962890625 ms - #testcase 2 - ok
time: 0.009033203125 ms - #testcase 3 - ok
time: 0.015869140625 ms - #testcase 4 - ok
time: 0.015869140625 ms - #testcase 5 - ok
time: 0.1279296875 ms - #testcase 6 - ok
time: 10227.974853515625 ms - #testcase 7 - ok
time: 9605.087158203125 ms - #testcase 8 - ok
```

The interesting part is `testcase 8`.
You can see that for this testcase `longest_common_subsequence_recursive_memoized` performs poorly (`105788.96801757812 ms ~= 105.8 seconds`), while for the other two functions it takes no more than 30 seconds (`longest_common_subsequence` being the best one by taking around 10 seconds to complete).

My question is: why does `longest_common_subsequence_recursive_memoized` perform so badly for testcase 8 while the implementation is quite similar to `longest_common_subsequence_recursive_memoized_mit`?

It still uses memoization, though, instead of directly accessing `res_matrix` and return values from there, it uses a decorator which wraps the recursive function to cache the results of the computation and return them right away when computations already computed before are required.

Thank you for your attention.

**EDIT:** After several trials, I found out that the performance problem seems to be related to the `@memoize_decorator` function.

If I rewrite the `longest_common_subsequence_recursive_memoized` function adding the equivalent test used in `longest_common_subsequence_recursive_memoized_mit` (MIT version):

```
def longest_common_subsequence_recursive_memoized(A, B):
    N = len(A)
    M = len(B)
    if N <= 0 or M <= 0:
        return []
    res_matrix = [[None] * M for i in range(N)]

    @memoize_decorator
    def lcs(i, j):
        if i <= -1 or j <= -1:
            return []
        if res_matrix[i][j] == None:
            if A[i] == B[j]:
                res_matrix[i][j] = lcs(i - 1, j - 1) + [A[i]]
            else:
                prev1 = lcs(i - 1, j)
                prev2 = lcs(i, j - 1)
                res_matrix[i][j] = prev1 if (
                    len(prev1)
                    >
                    len(prev2)
                ) else prev2
        return res_matrix[i][j]

    lcs(N - 1, M - 1)
    return res_matrix[-1][-1]
```

Even with this modification, the function is still slow for `testcase 8`:

```
...
time: 95080.388671875 ms - #testcase 8 - ok
...
```

And if I comment the `@memoize_decorator` line:

```
def longest_common_subsequence_recursive_memoized(A, B):
    N = len(A)
    M = len(B)
    if N <= 0 or M <= 0:
        return []
    res_matrix = [[None] * M for i in range(N)]

    # @memoize_decorator <--- Comment
    def lcs(i, j):
        if i <= -1 or j <= -1:
            return []
        if res_matrix[i][j] == None:
            if A[i] == B[j]:
                res_matrix[i][j] = lcs(i - 1, j - 1) + [A[i]]
            else:
                prev1 = lcs(i - 1, j)
                prev2 = lcs(i, j - 1)
                res_matrix[i][j] = prev1 if (
                    len(prev1)
                    >
                    len(prev2)
                ) else prev2
        return res_matrix[i][j]

    lcs(N - 1, M - 1)
    return res_matrix[-1][-1]
```

Then the function is far way faster for `testcase 8` (`~24 secs` instead of `~95 secs`):

```
...
time: 24229.078857421875 ms - #testcase 8 - ok
...
```

So I guess the performance drawbacks come from `memoize_decorator`, as if I remove it, I get a performance gain. Strange enough, as memoization should speed up repetitive computations.

But in the case of this modified `longest_common_subsequence_recursive_memoized` function it doesn't really matter if its inner function is memoized with `memoize_decorator`, as at this point because `longest_common_subsequence_recursive_memoized` already uses memoization on its own through `res_matrix` and the `if res_matrix[i][j] == None:` test.

So my final diagnosis is that the `~95 secs` are related to the code in `inner_fn`:

```
    ...
        if args in cache:
            return cache[args]
        ret = fn(*args)
        cache[args] = ret
        return ret
    ...
```

On the other hand, if I leave `longest_common_subsequence_recursive_memoized` as it was before **but** **without** `@memoize_decorator` (renaming it to `longest_common_subsequence_recursive`):

```
def longest_common_subsequence_recursive(A, B):
    N = len(A)
    M = len(B)
    if N <= 0 or M <= 0:
        return []
    res_matrix = [[[]] * M for i in range(N)]

    # @memoize_decorator <--- Without memoization
    def recursion(i, j):
        if i <= -1 or j <= -1:
            return []
        elif A[i] == B[j]:
            res_matrix[i][j] = recursion(i - 1, j - 1) + [A[i]]
        else:
            prev1 = recursion(i - 1, j)
            prev2 = recursion(i, j - 1)
            res_matrix[i][j] = prev1 if (
                len(prev1)
                >
                len(prev2)
            ) else prev2
        return res_matrix[i][j]

    recursion(N - 1, M - 1)
    return res_matrix[-1][-1]
```

Then the execution time is even worse and it gets far way more than `95 seconds` to execute.

Memoization implemented with a decorator in this case seems to be something in between the naive recursive unoptimized solution (`longest_common_subsequence_recursive`) and the better optimized solutions (the MIT inline memoization version and the dynamic programming one).

Would be happy to hear what you think about this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: why does longest_common_subsequence_recursive_memoized
>   perform so badly for testcase 8 while the implementation is quite
>   similar to longest_common_subsequence_recursive_memoized_mit?

The primary performance difference I find between the two is that the MIT version has:

```
res_matrix = [[None] * M for i in range(N)]
...
if res_matrix[i][j] == None:
```

while yours uses:

```
res_matrix = [[[]] * M for i in range(N)]
```

*and no equivalent test*.  If we modify yours to incorporate the same initialization and test as MIT, and decorate with Python's own `rlu_cache()` from **functools**, so we can interrogate the cache, we get:

```
CacheInfo(hits=380620, misses=17610383, maxsize=128, currsize=128)
time: 19195.7060546875 ms - #testcase 8 - ok
```

Increasing cache size from the default 128 improves performance:

```
CacheInfo(hits=8988004, misses=9002999, maxsize=4096, currsize=4096)
time: 16645.57080078125 ms - #testcase 8 - ok
```

But only to a point and then makes no further difference.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. `while yours uses: ... and no equivalent test.` Thank you for your reply. The question that comes to my mind then is why doesn't the `if args in cache:` in `@memoize_decorator(recursion)` of `longest_common_subsequence_recursive_memoized ` work almost equivalently as the `if res_matrix[i][j] == None:` condition in `longest_common_subsequence_recursive_memoized_mit` ? Even if the memoized `recusion` function returns saving the return value in the cache, it seems that the cache doesn't boost the execution... This is the main difference I still don't understand

Comment: Could you provide an example showing the differences between the two approaches?

Comment: I tried to play with the code again and it seems that the overhead comes from the `@memoize_decorator` decorator function. Even if I make `longest_common_subsequence_recursive_memoized` the same as the MIT version, if I wrap the inner `recursion()` function with `@memoize_decorator`, it takes up to 90 seconds to complete for testcase 8...

Comment: If I comment the `@memoize_decorator` line, then `longest_common_subsequence_recursive_memoized` (modified to be identical to the MIT function with the equivalent `if res_matrix[i][j] == None:` test) runs within 25 seconds... Could it be because of the `cache` data structure used in `memoize_decorator`?